# How to replace String characters in C#

Tags: c#

I would like to replace specific String characters based on some integers value passed dynamically to its index.

Unfortunately, String.Replace() expects String value as its arguments. So could anyone please tell me how can I make my requirement possible?

Comment: Example input(s) and output(s) please.

Comment: String s = "abc"; s = s.replace(1,2); I would like to pass integer value instead of string value in replace method. If that is not possible, then can I do this?

Comment: 2 upvotes for this question? seriously?

Comment: @Dusk: In that case why don't you just call to string on the integers?

Comment: @Brian Rasmussen - i thin he wants to replace the 1st character of the string with the 2nd character of a string. as to *why* he would want to do that, nfi.

Comment: @RPM1984: In that case I got it wrong and yet the question has 3 upvotes ...

Comment: It doesn't make much more sense with the comment.  What is the *new* String, and why?

Comment: Yeah screw this. +1 vote to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's usually better with changing strings to use a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/2839d5h5%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). It has a StringBuilder.Replace method that can replace characters.

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable; to change an individual character you might use:

```
char[] chars = oldString.ToCharArray();
chars[index] = newChar;
string newString = new string(chars);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to replace lot of words within the string then it is always better to use stringBuilder. String is slower compared to StringBuilder. To come over limitations in String datatype, stringbuilder was introduced.